# Null response when parsing value to a function, stuck on it. Is there something I am missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a Point of Sale cart module to sharpen my javascript skills. I am currently trying to calculate the total of a product, by multiplying it's price and quantity needed. I am loading the products through a json file, so far so good. But I have a problem in this javaScript function. The quantity is being loaded through the HTML as shown below.

```
function AddToCart(food){
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `
    <tr data-price='100' data-quantity='5' id='${food.FoodID}'>
    <td>
        ${food.FoodName}
    </td>
     <td id = "PriceFood">
        ${food.FoodPrice}
    </td>
    <td>
        **<input class='' id="Quantity" type="number" min="1" max="9" step="1" value="1">**
    </td>
    <td id="ProductTotal">
        **${getTotal(food.FoodPrice, document.getElementById('#Quantity'))}**
    </td>
     <td>
        <a href="#" class="remove" data-id="${food.FoodID}">X</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    `
    ;
    cart_content.appendChild(row);

}


    function getTotal(price, qty){
        console.log(price, qty)
        return Number(price) * qty;
    }
```

By running the result above in the console. console.log(price, qty) returns this :-

100 null

The price is being parsed but it returns a null for the quantity.
I can't really be able to identify the problem why it returns a null. 
Some help would be appreciated..thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`.getElementById()` does just that, gets an element by its `id`. Because of this you don't prepend the `id` with a `#` as you are doing here:

```
document.getElementById('#Quantity')
```

Remove the `#` to correctly get the quantity element.

Then, to get the value of that element, you'll need to use `qty.value`, not just `qty`.

Comment: Thanks. This is a really important error. I didn't notice this. Although I am still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @Derrickjamal Then there must be something else wrong with other code that you haven't shown. Please update your question to include the relevant HTML and JavaScript as well, so we can replicate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById`, assumes you are supplying the ID of the DOM node, therefore you don't need to precede it with `#`.

With that, you would be returning just the DOM node to the function - you need to return the value of the input, like so:

`**${getTotal(food.FoodPrice, document.getElementById('Quantity').value)}**`

Comment: It's always a better idea to return the element, rather than a property of an element. That way, you can use multiple properties of the returned element without having to requery the DOM for the element again.

Comment: I agree with this and it's good to point out as a best practice.Though `getTotal()` I see as a quite an explicit function which is just doing some simple math. So it seems sensible that you  wouldn't want to use more info from the DOM node, and you could re-use it elsewhere in JS if it just accepts two numbers as its arguments.

Comment: Thanks @Derrickjamal - feel free to mark as accepted answer, however Scott Marcus' answer would also be correct, and he answered just before me, so... :)